# Host key verification failed error for submodule in gitlab pipeline

Tags: gitlab, continuous-integration, devops, pipeline, gitlab-ci-runner

I am working on CI/CD pipeline (GitLab) build and I want to update my submodule. ( In local `git submodule update --init --recursive --remote` works well). But the same thing in the pipeline gives the below error:

```
Host key verification failed.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I try to use `git submodule update --init --recursive --remote` command in the scripts section. But it works well in the terminal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create project access tokens, if you don't have permissions ask the admin to create

To create a project access token:

1. On the top bar, select Main menu > Projects and find your project.
2. Settings > Access Tokens.
3. Enter a name.
4. Select a role for the token.
5. Select  Create project access token.

Edit the .gitmodules file from your project. Enter the newly created username and token below

```
url = https://$(USERNAME):$(PROJECT_ACCESS_TOKEN)@github.com/user/repository.git
```

Set the `GIT_SUBMODULE_STRATEGY : normal` in your CI/CD